# Openshift: Is it possible to make different pods of the same deployment to use different resources?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, openshift

In Openshift, say there are two pods of the same deployment in Test env. Is it possible to make one pod to use/connect to database1, make another pod to use/connect to dababase2 via label or configuration?

Comment: This is not how deployments are intended to work. Pods within a single deployment are intended to be _identical_ copies. Changing which database the pod consumes is breaking this paradigm. I would use two separate deployments.

Comment: Could you add more info on these pods?  I'm curious if all containers are the same or you are using a few containers (sidecar ones). Also it would be good if you could shed some light on background for this question

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have created two diff pods with same code base or image containing same compiled code. Using spring profiling,passed two different arguments for connection to oracle database.

for example

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

How about try to use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/) for deploying each pod ? `StatefulSet` make each pod uses each PersistentVolume, so if you place each configuration file which is configured with other database connection data on each PersistentVolume, each pod can use other database each other. Because the pod can refer different config file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  serviceName: "app"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: example.com/app:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: databaseconfig
          mountPath: /usr/local/databaseconfig
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: databaseconfig
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Mi
```